# What does a successful Compass/Sass install look like?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Long time lurker, first time poster.

I am moving from LESS to Sass, and would also like to begin using Compass on a few projects. I am using CodeKit to watch and initiate new Compass based projects, but I have also tried this from the command line with the same result. My question boils dow to this:

Creating a new compass project with "compass create [project-name]" builds out the basic structure for a Compass project, along with a config.rb file and three .scss files (screen.scss, print.scss, and ie.scss).

But why isn't the project pre-populated with the latest core Compass .scss files, helpers, etc? Am I wrong to expect a payload of core Compass files (Such as these: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/) to show up in my project?

I can find them if I drill down to say, /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1... , but these are global and for all projects, not for customizing on a per project basis.

I feel like I'm missing a starter kit of .scss files with a default set of variables. Or that I am otherwise getting off on the wrong foot with how new projects are being initiated with Compass.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I usually like to go wandering through GitHub, [seeing what I can find](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sass%20compass&type=Everything&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1), when I'm looking for some examples or templates to work from. There's a [few projects](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sass) [that happen](http://mhs.github.com/scout-app/) [to fall out](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass). Don't know if that's exactly what you're after, but I'm sure it's there somewhere. Also, I think Bootstrap is a Sass project (not sure about Compass).

Comment: (Thanks). I guess that's where things got strange in my mental model of Compass. It feels like it's role would be to provide those starter files for each new project, and to do so in a way that exposed them a little better. But it's sinking in now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compass is envirment for project. There is no need for it to be in your project dir. You can update it any time. You can use compass watch or sass with compass as lib. All you need is your project and config for compass. It's better way than have it in all projects especially if you have control version in project. In my way I just writing minimal deps files and that's all.

Starter kit creates in sass folder by default. So you don't missing nothing. But there is a clean files. All other stuff you should do like you want or try skeletons from github for example.

Comment: I had some problems related to the use of CodeKit, resolved somewhat by linking to the Sass binary directly. I've spent the last few days absorbed in Foundation, and it's improved things for me enormously.